# Just created a new subdomain and main .htaccess file is causing a 404. What to do?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I just created a new subdomain (subdomain.example.com) and the main site htaccess file (for example.com) is causing issues by trying to direct the subdomain to the same rules as the main site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think I need to provide code.  On a whim, before I posted this question, I made a new .htaccess file in the subdomain directory and it solved the issues.  Now for each subdomain I add, I will just have to keep in mind that this is something I will have to do!

Hope this helped someone else!